# Feeding Azure Event Hub data to ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, react-hooks, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to read data from the Azure Event Hub and display it on a simple web app using ReactJS. I've used the code sample from Microsoft to read Azure data, and this works fine standalone. I have an IoT temperature sensor and every time the sensor sends I receive the value from the function in the console:

```
const consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient("$Default", 
connectionString, clientOptions);

async function getTemperature() {

consumerClient.subscribe({
  processEvents: async(events, context) => {
      for(const event of events){
         var temperature = event.body.temperature;
         var humidity = event.body.humidity;
         console.log(temperature);
         console.log(humidity);
      }
  },
  processError: async (err, context) => {
      console.log(`Error : ${err}`);
  }
});
}

getTemperature().catch((error) => {
   console.error("Error running sample:", error);
});
```

I now wish to use this in ReactJS component, something like this:

```
const returnTemperature = () => {
    return ( 
        <div className="environment">
            <p>The temperature is { temperature }&#176; Celcius.</p>
        </div>
     );
}

export default returnTemperature;
```

I am new to ReactJS and I cannot get my head around how to update the value on the web page every time the temperature received by the Azure function is updated. I have looked into useState/useEffect but not got anything working.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I made assumptions that you can work with functional components.

```
const Temperature = () => {
  const [temperature, setTemperature] = useState();
  const consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(
    "$Default",
    connectionString,
    clientOptions
  );

  const getTemperature = async () => {
    consumerClient.subscribe({
      processEvents: async (events, context) => {
        for (const event of events) {
          var temperature = event.body.temperature;
          var humidity = event.body.humidity;
          setTemperature(temperature);
          console.log(temperature);
          console.log(humidity);
        }
      },
      processError: async (err, context) => {
        console.log(`Error : ${err}`);
      },
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTemperature().catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error running sample:", error);
    });
    return () => {
      // cleanUpFunction if applicable
      // consumerClient.unsubscribe()
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="environment">
      <p>The temperature is {temperature}&#176; Celcius.</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `useEffect()` with empty dependencies `[]` array acts like `componentDidMount` as in, it only runs once. i.e calls your `getTemperature` on first load.

After that, the `setState()` will keep the temperature value updated, and re-render the component whenever the temperature updates.